# lpSolve - find maximum value - formula with multiplications

Tags: r, max, solver, lpsolve

I'm looking for a way to use lpSolve in a similar way to how I use it succesfully in Excel. I've calculated elasticity for various product. Based on whether a product is elasticity or not elastic I want to give an advice on which price to ask.

I have the following values:

```
current.price = 15
sales.lastmonth = 50
elasticity = -1.5
```

And I want to optimize the sales.prediction by changing the suggested.price

Formula:
sales.prediction = (sales.lastmonth - ((abs(elasticity)*(suggested.price-current.price))*(sales.lastmonth/current.price)))*suggested.price

I've tried the following:

```
# install.packages("lpSolve")
library(lpSolve)

objective.fn <- c(sales.prediction) # determine what the objective is

# constrain sales.lastmonth and current.price
const.mat <- matrix(c(1,1),ncol=1,byrow=T)
const.dir <- c("=","=")
const.rhs <- c(sales.lastmonth, current.price)

lp("max",objective.fn,const.mat,const.dir,const.rhs,compute.sens=TRUE)
```

Any suggestions?

## -----------

**EDIT - V2: Based on the comment below, I would like to add the constraint that the suggested.price should be at max 25% higher of 25% lower than the the suggested price I have in my mind without the optimization. For example, let's say I am already thinking about lowering the price to 12.5. Is that possible as well?**

Comment: Can you write out your constraints? These values of yours seem to be constant, this is not constrained opzimization?

Comment: The objective function shown is quadratic, not linear, in suggested price so linear programming is not the right approach.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Do you have a suggestion for a better way to optimzie the price?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are simply trying to optimize (maximize) this function, there are no constraints since your variables are constant. If this is true then you can do

```
optimize(
  f=function(x){
    sales.lastmonth-((abs(elasticity)*(x-current.price))*(sales.lastmonth/current.price))*x
  },
  interval=c(-100,100),
  maximum=T
)

$maximum
[1] 7.5

$objective
[1] 331.25
```

maximum at 7.5.

**Edit:** a simple hack to limit the optimization is to use the interval argument, for your edit `interval=c(current.price*0.75,current.price*1.25)`.

Comment: I've altered the interval argument, is that possible as well?

Comment: @FrankBeke If by that you mean that you want to find an optimal value in a custom interval, say [3,6], then yes, you can input this in `interval`.

Comment: Yes, I already figured it out. Thanks!